# Reading a json file into a template using [ngForOf]

Tags: json, angular

I'm new to Angular 4. I need to replace a constant file('nsv.ts) with a json file for reading a list of navigation elements.
This is my const file 'nav.ts':

```
export const navigation = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard'    
  },
  {
    name: 'Client',
    url: '/client'
   }
   ....
]
```

In 'sidebar-nav.component.ts':

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

// Import navigation elements
import { navigation } from './../../nav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav',
  template: `
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <ng-template ngFor let-navitem [ngForOf]="navigation">
         .....
        </ng-template>
      </ul>
    </nav>`
```

I was wondering to use a service where to read the json and then pass it to sidebar-nav.component.ts but no idea on how do it. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do these simple steps

1)take your data json file
like **data.json**,

2)put this file in assets folder

3)after that call file using angular/http service

Comment: Do I have to call the json file directly into the template? No service class ?

Comment: first you need to get the data in your componet using http services, after that from ts-> html you can print